# Data not displaying after reordering the layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am created a layout that contains parent as scrollview->LinearLayout(vertical orientation) inside that,it has 13 textView. Data's was not displaying while i tried to reorder the textview. I don't get any error message also.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#EAEAEA"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ors_id"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ors_jobtitle"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsjobtitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ors_requestdate"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsRequestDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ors_requestorname"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsRequestorName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ors_requestorteam"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsReqestorTeam"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/request_type"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viewdetailsors"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/view_details"                    
                android:textColor="#31B1E0" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsReqestorType"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblorsBackFillEmployee"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/back_fill_emp"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsBackFillEmployee"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/requester_comments"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsReqestorComments"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblorsTeamHeadComments"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/team_head_comments"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsTeamHeadComments"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblorsDivisionHeadComments"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/division_head_comments"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsDivisionHeadComments"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ors_expiredate"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orsExpireDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/comments"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ManagerComments"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLength="199"
            android:text="@string/approved" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: post your necessary codes...

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some code

Comment: @Navaneethan Please post your XML layout code.

Comment: scrollview should have only 1 direct element..I think you have child elements...

Comment: @Subburaj Scrollview has one direct element LinearLayout. LinearLayout has child elements TextView...

Answer (score 0):

The code you entered is missing the scroll view tag and properties [in the beginning].
I don't have comment permission [sorry for hacking comment and i will remove the post].

Comment: This tip might goes to the comment I believe, not in the answer.

Comment: Actually there is scrollview on the top but it not showing in the question <ScrollView android:id="@+id/sub_content_view_ors" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">